# Using connection string in if statement

Tags: .net, vb.net, if-statement, scope

What could be the problem with my connection string here pls. It reports cnn is undeclared.

```
        Dim cnn As New OleDbConnection
        If rdbtnNewDbase.Checked = True Then
             Dim cnn As new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Persist Security Info=false; Data Source=..\HCHPClosedIn11.mdb")
        ElseIf rdbtnOldDbase.Checked = True Then
            Dim cnn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Persist Security Info=false; Data Source=..\HCHPold.mdb")
        End If
```

Comment: are you getting an error?  why not create two connections and access them conditionally?

Comment: why do you keep re-dimming cnn. Why not do `cnn=xxxxx` in the if statement

Comment: Does that even compile? Answer it doesn't. "Variable 'cnn' hides a variable in an enclosing block" - try looking that error up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You try to redeclare your connection object within `If/End If` scope. As it is, your code can't even compile. Moreover, variables can't be used outside the scope they were declared in.

What you really want to do is this:

```
Dim cnn As OleDbConnection
If rdbtnNewDbase.Checked = True Then
    cnn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Persist Security Info=false; Data Source=..\HCHPClosedIn11.mdb")
ElseIf rdbtnOldDbase.Checked = True Then
    cnn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Persist Security Info=false; Data Source=..\HCHPold.mdb")
End If
```

Or, to make it shorter and clearer:

```
Dim cs As String = 
    "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Persist Security Info=false; Data Source=..\" &
    If(rdbtnNewDbase.Checked, "HCHPClosedIn11.mdb", "HCHPold.mdb")

Dim cnn As New OleDbConnection(cs)
```

Comment: In your shortened example shouldn't that be Iff as opposed to just plain if?

Comment: Since VS2008 inline `If` statements are permitted in [tag:VB.NET].

Comment: @Dom Use of `iif` should be avoided whenever possible, it's for backwards compatibility only.  It will actually execute both the True and False portions regardless of the condition. `If` is the .NET way to do it, with proper short circuiting and all.

Comment: @BradleyUffner +1, although in this precise scenario it wouldn't do any difference since both parts are string literals.

Comment: I hadn't realised that that was actually permitted (and since vs2008 to boot,   shame on me!).  Thanks for todays learn something new bit.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```vb
Using cnn As New OleDbConnection(string.Format(
    "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Persist Security Info=false; Data Source=..\{0}", 
     If(rdbtnNewDbase.Checked, "HCHPClosedIn11.mdb", "HCHPHold.mdb" ))

    '...
End Using
```

Comment: This is of course assuming the connection is to be used immediately. Still, +1.

Comment: I believe in short object lifetimes in .Net: if you're creating the connection object instance long before you use it, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: That's right, but that doesn't mean the connection has to be used in the exact scope it was created. A factory class's `CreateConnection` method for instance would return the connection it creates. It would therefore be the caller's responsibility to dispose of it.